# sin/cos = cos/sin

Tags: trigonometry, fake-proofs

To begin with, let's note the following:

$$
\tan = \frac{\sin}{\cos}
\\
\sin = \tan \cdot \cos
\\
\cos = \frac{\sin}{\tan}
$$

If we replace one of the functions in $\frac{\cos}{\sin}$ according to the definitions above:

$$
\frac{\cos}{\sin} = \frac{\frac{\sin}{\tan}}{\sin} = \frac{{\sin}}{\tan\sin} = \tan
$$

or:

$$
\frac{\cos}{\sin} = \frac{\cos}{\tan\cos} = \tan
$$

So it looks like $\sin\div\cos = \cos\div\sin$ what can't be truth (except for 45°×n). I must have made a mistake somewhere but I am not sure where. How come?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\tan x}=\cot x$..All youve shown is that $\cos x$ divided by $\sin x$ is cotangent..not tangent...

Comment: $\frac{\operatorname{sin}}{\operatorname{tan}\operatorname{sin}}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{tan}}$, not $\operatorname{tan}$. $\frac{1}{\operatorname{tan}}$ has its own name: $\operatorname{cot}$, or **co**tangent.

Comment: @Utkarsh You’re wrong. Past introductory calculus, we refer to functions as $f$, $g$, etc., without writing their values at $x$. And it makes good sense to add, multiply, divide, compose functions, writing $f+g$, $fg$, $f/g$, $f\circ g$. Of course, this doesn’t address the issue in this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cancelled improperly:
$$\require{cancel}
\frac{\sin \theta}{\tan \theta \sin \theta}=
\frac{\cancel{\sin \theta}}{\tan \theta \cancel{\sin \theta}}=
\frac{1}{\tan \theta  }=\cot \theta
$$

Comment: they didnt cancel improperly, they thought $1$ divided by tangent is tangent..

Comment: I've taught/tutored students who thought that if everything goes away on top, it's no longer on the bottom of a fraction, so who's to say.

Answer (score 0):

Note,

$$\frac{1}{\tan x}=\cot x.$$

Comment: yep, I know but it's offtop